# Is metro UI copyrighted or can it be implemented?

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-metro

I am designing a web app for reading. And I was wondering if i can use elements of metro ui inside the application. Is it permitted by Microsoft?

Comment: Voting off-topic.  What you're asking for basically sounds like legal advice.  You probably should talk to a copyright lawyer before you start throwing money or significant amounts of time on a design that could have some chance of infringing on copyright or trademark.  Or at least read a book or two on copyright law for graphic designers/UX people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks there're several websites and apps have already used metro style, like:

- Google I/O: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html
- Android Market: http://gadgetfeel.com/android-market-update-similar-to-metro-ui/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can be implemented. Here is a project on GitHub which provides a Web UI Library [Metro-UI-CSS](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS). The project website: [MetroUI](http://metroui.org.ua/).

I have been using this recently; it is pretty nice!

Comment: Just because it is technically feasible doesn't mean it's legally sound to do so.

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions.

Comment: @bmargulies: No, let's not do this; the community decides if something is off-topic, but until a question is closed as such, everyone is free to provide answers. This one is quite clearly off-topic, of course, but please do not go around telling people off for providing answers to questions while they are still open.